# How to apply the effect "You may treat all Constructs as Mechana Constructs" in Ascension game?

Tags: ascension

Could I treat any Construct in center row as Mechana Construct and accure them acquire it as a Mechana Construct?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this effect combined with others can lead to infinite combos, such as combining Reclamax (*mechana construct: discard into your discard to be allowed to purchase a mechana construct from the void as though it were in center*), Tablet of Time's Dawn (*enlightened construct: banish into void to take an extra turn after this one*), Dimension Diver (*treat all constructs as mechana constructs wherever they are*), and a deck consisting of almost exclusively draw a card cards with at most four that don't.  You'll be able to buy and use tablet every turn.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, once you have the effect of "You may treat all constructs as Mechana Constructs", this applies to acquisition (e.g. runes that can only be used to purchase Mechana constructs can be used to buy any construct under this effect) and to effects that count the number of Mechana constructs in play. (There may be other effects from later expansions.)